# Error coming from `npm install` npm init @shopify/app@latest

Tags: npm, shopify, npm-install, shopify-app, node-gyp

Whenever I try to install a shopify starter app, I get this error below. I've tried with different version of node and npm. My default is node 20 but I've tried node 21, 18, and 16.  I've tried to globall install node-gyp and reinstall node. Ive reinstalled node with nvm and brew (currently back with nvm) but no luck.
`gyp: binding.gyp not found (cwd: /private/var/folders/06/bhgmqwc16277rcmgqyqzfxs40000gn/T/c2ea0f5ec439cf3a3edf63947ba45b27/app/nod e_modules/@shopify/app/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents) while trying to load binding.gyp gyp ERR! configure error gyp ERR! stack Error:` gyp`failed with exit code: 1`

Comment: I had the same issue. I removed node_modules global and reinstalled again, it worked for me.